# Как перегрузить операторы `+, -, /, *, ==` для собственных типов?

Tags: java

Как перегрузить оперторы `+, -, /, *, ==` для собственных типов?

Comment: Java не поддерживает перегрузки операторов

Comment: Что за странные войны правок? Исправляю опечатки, вам нравится откатывать к неправильным вариантам?

Comment: Вы не думаете о том, что ваш вопрос нужен кому-то кроме вас - спросили, получили ответ, а дальше хоть трава не гори. А есть люди, которые в интернете задают вопрос и попадают на уже ранее кем-то заданные вопросы. Поэтому спеллинг достаточно важен, я надеюсь, что это вам теперь более понятно. И не надо видеть вокруг одних кармофермеров, мир гораздо более разнообразнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Java не поддерживает перегрузку операторов.

Реализовать арифметику собственных типов можно с помощью методов класса.

Простой пример:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    public MyObject(int x, int y) {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return mX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return mY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + mX + ", " + mY + "]";
    }

    public static MyObject multiply(MyObject firstObject, MyObject secondObject) {
        int x = firstObject.getX()*secondObject.getX();
        int y = firstObject.getY()*secondObject.getY();
        return new MyObject(x, y);
    }
}
```

---

```
MyObject firstObject = new MyObject(2,5);
MyObject secondObject = new MyObject(3,8);
MyObject result = MyObject.multiply(firstObject, secondObject);
System.out.println(firstObject + " * " + secondObject + " = " + result);
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 5] * [3, 8] = [6, 40]
```

Так же метод `multiply(...)` можно сделать не статическим и осуществлять манипуляции над `this` и одним переданным объектом. Тогда вызвать метод  `multiply(...)` можно будет так:

```
firstObject.multiply(secondObject);
```

Comment: А как тогда реализовать арифметику собственных типов в принципе?

Comment: @user229157, С помощью методов класса.

Comment: Типа такого `x.add(y)`?

Comment: @user229157, Да.

Comment: крутяк  спасибон

Comment: А минус как назвать, что-то в `BigInteger` не нашёл?

Comment: КАК МИНУС НАЗВАТЬ ТО

Comment: @user229157, [`public BigInteger subtract(BigInteger val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#subtract(java.math.BigInteger)).

Comment: ясно спасибо!!!